# Restricting records to one side of the join in a self join query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, self-join

Consider a table (name Term) as follows:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Label] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
[Uri] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL
```

Now, consider that there are two categories defined: CategoryId 1 and CategoryId 2 and there are multiple terms that belong either to category1 or category2. I'm trying to find those Terms that have the same URI but different labels in these two categories, or within a single category of those two. To do so, I tried to write a self join SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id AS TermId1,
    t2.Id AS TermId2
FROM
    Term t1 INNER JOIN Term t2 ON t1.Uri = t2.Uri
WHERE
    t1.CategoryId IN (@CategoryId1, @CategoryId2) AND
    t2.CategoryId IN (@CategoryId1, @CategoryId2) AND
    t1.Label <> t2.Label
```

This works fine, but each row is returned twice... For example,

TermId1, TermId2
TermId2, TermId1

If the termId1 is different from termId2, then there's no need to have the reverse order result. So, how am I supposed to get results once?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  You may not need the group by

```
    SELECT t1.Id AS TermId1, t2.Id AS TermId2
    FROM
        Term t1 
        INNER JOIN Term t2 
          ON t1.Uri = t2.Uri
         AND t1.Label <> t2.Label
         AND t1.Id < t2.Id      
    WHERE
            t1.CategoryId IN (@CategoryId1, @CategoryId2) 
        and t2.CategoryId IN (@CategoryId1, @CategoryId2)          
    group by t1.Id, t2.Id
    order by t1.Id, t2.Id
```